# Why is the output something I didn't set

Tags: ruby

In this code from a book, there is a variable I didn't use, and it is set to a specific value:

```
def secret_formula(started)
  jelly_beans = started * 500
  jars = jelly_beans / 1000
  crates = jars / 100
  return jelly_beans, jars, crates
end

start_point = 1000
bears, jars, cratesm = secret_formula(start_point)
puts bears
puts jars
puts cratesm
```

The output was:

```
500000
500
5
```

Comment: The line `bears,jars,cratesm = secret_formula(start_point)` creates and assigns to the three variables on the right hand side. The variable names in the method are used to transfer the values "out", and are independent labels to the ones outside the method.

Answer (score 3):

Your `secret_formula` method is returning 3 values.

You are then assigning those 3 values into `bears, jars, cratesm`. Don't get confused about what you've called variables inside your method - they are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind for Ruby that variables which are defined within a function are not (generally speaking) available outside of the function.  What you have done is defined 3 new **local variables**.  These 3 variables are local to your function definition, and they will vanish into thin air as soon as your function is done being called.

The end of your function **returns** 3 **values**.  This is helpful to remember.  It's not returning your 3 variables - those variables are local and are just about to vanish.  The function is returning 3 *values*.  Now, whoever calls that function gets to decide what names they would like to use for the variables which are assigned the 3 returned values.

So, if we modify your code by changing up some of the variable names, this would work too:

```
def secret_formula(started)
  jelly_beans = started * 500
  jars = jelly_beans / 1000
  crates = jars / 100
  return jelly_beans, jars, crates
end

start_point = 1000
milk, cartons, trucks = secret_formula(start_point)
puts milk
puts cartons
puts trucks
```

That's the nice thing about functions.  You don't really have to know what is happening on the inside, or how any of it works, or even *what the variables in the function are named*.  All you need is confidence that it works like it's supposed to (although it would be nice to have some good documentation alongside the function so that you know what it expects as inputs and what you can expect as outputs).

Here's another example to illustrate the point even further..

```
def secret_formula(X)
  N = X * 500
  I = N / 1000
  Z = I / 100
  return N, I, Z
end

start_point = 1000
bears, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)
puts bears
puts jars
puts crates
```